# Reconstructing a graph from set of sequences of edges

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have posted the same problem to [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239632/reconstructing-a-graph-from-set-of-sequences-of-edges), not sure where it fits better.

I have the following problem to solve: Given a set of sequences of edges of an undirected, planar, connected graph, find a "reasonable" reconstruction of the graph. There is an unknown number of vertices in the graph, but it's given that each edge in each given sequence shares a vertex with the edge next to it in the sequence. We could further assume, that all the sequences start with the same edge.

Ideally, I would need an algorithm to reconstruct the graph.

Has such problem been already studied or does anyone see a way to transform it to another known problem? So far, I can only think of genetic algorithms.

Comment: You should wait more time before cross-posting your question.

Comment: Interesting problem (+1), but you need to be a bit more explicit about what you would consider to be a "reasonable" reconstruction. Obviously, your goal of reconstructing the graph is unreasonable unless you place some requirements on the lengths of the sequences and the number of sequences. I'm not up on the literature, but I'd be surprised if no one has considered this problem before. MO is probably your best bet--see what they say.